# Good practice for setting up multiple WCF services in virtual directories under one root url

Tags: wcf, iis

I am setting up our server to handle all our WCF web services. What I want to know is, what is the best practice for proper isolation of each service under one root domain?
I'm using something like http://api.ourdomain.com and I want each of our client's WCF services to be isolated in separate virtual directories like http://api.ourdomain.com/client1.
I'd like it so that if any one fails/bombs they won't affect other live WCF services running.
Normally I isolate them by website, but since these are all under one 'roof' so to speak, Ihave to do some IIS trickery to properly isolate them.
I had setup a virtual directory and had it as it's own 'app' but I was getting the following error:
"It is not possible to run two different versions of ASP.NET in the same IIS process. Please use the IIS Administration Tool to reconfigure your server to run the application in a separate process."
Which is strange since I had them both set to use .NET 4.0 framework, so, I'm not sure what happened.

Comment: Are you sure that they're both using the **full** framework, and not the idiot **client** framework, on one of them?

Comment: yea, I already thought of that, lol. ...'idiot framework'..lol

Comment: point of note: there might be an issue with our IIS in general. (It's on an old 2003 box, currently) We started a new app pool and pointed each vir dir to a diff app pool and now it seems friendly ... I'll post back in a day or so after a restart or two to verify that was the solution.